# Finding and selecting cell with the same value of another cell in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm fairly new to working with macros in excel. I've made a dropdown list in sheet 1, cell A1. Based on the value of this cell, I need my macro to find and select the cell in sheet 2 (which is one unique cell) that corresponds with the value chosen in the dropdown list. I want to use this as a reference cell to copy a range.

Any suggestions on how I can do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try recording a macro and start from there?

Answer (score 0):

[Range.Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) can get that done for you.

`Sheet2.Cells.Find(What:=DropdownValue).Select`

Be careful of doing it in a single line though. This will raise an error if the `Find` method doesn't find any matches since you can't do `Select` on `Nothing`.

It's safer to do it in separate lines like:

```vb
Dim rFind As Range
Set rFind = Sheet2.Cells.Find(What:=DropdownValue)
If Not rFind Is Nothing Then rFind.Select
```

And for reliability and completeness, you should include the other arguments of `Find`, to ensure the method is using the matching rules that you expect. The most critical ones are LookIn, LookAt and MatchCase.

```vb
Set rFind = Sheet2.Cells.Find( _
                               What:=DropdownValue, _
                               LookIn:=xlValues, _
                               LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                               MatchCase:=True _
                             )
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I can't seem to get it to work, though. When I try these lines I get a runtime error: "select method of range class failed". Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry, you need to activate `Sheet2` before you can `Select` a range from it. Try adding `Sheet2.Activate` before doing `Select`.